# Which technique is the best for extracting location from a Resume in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, nlp

I am working on creating a parser for job description. Here I have to extract every project details separately.  I have used NLTK and Stanford but the results are not accurate. Can anyone suggest a module to use which provides best results

Comment: Have you looked into named entity recognition? spaCy has a module for it: https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition

Comment: Thanks for the info steph but i can able to install spacy but whenever i import spacy and run it , It shows this error " ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.  "

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands to install Spacy

```
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

Then you can tag your dataset and train the model on that or even you can use the pre-trained model.

Comment: Thanks for the help @TARUN KUMAR I have installed it.

Answer (score 0):

A full working example with spacy:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = u"Software Engineer job in San Francisco, California, USA"
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ in ['GPE', 'LOC']:
        print ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_

San Francisco 25 38 GPE
California 40 50 GPE
USA 52 55 GPE
```

Note that you can train the model further, by giving it more labeled examples. See the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities).